# Jenkinsfile dynamic variable in defined function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to set up scheduled runs for certain branches in certain environments and and coding that into our Jenkinsfile. As different branches are pushed to different environments for testing, I'd like to be able to dynamically update them. The code below works fine if I use string for the branch names inside `getCronJobsForBranch()` but, once I set them dynamically, I get the following error(whether I use syntax `var`, `$var`, `"$var"`, `${var}`, or anything else like that):

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: [branch/var name] for class: WorkflowScript`

I am including the basic code below. The defined branch vars are accessible in the pipeline and work as expected, so I assume I somehow need to get this in a stage/node/step, but I'm not quite sure how. Thanks for the help!

```
def branchInEnv1 = "branch_one"
def branchInEnv2 = "branch_two"
def branchInEnv3 = "branch_three"

def getCronJobsForBranch(branchName) {
    if (branchName == branchInEnv1) { // doesn't recognize var here
        '''
           0 3 * * * %ENV=env1
        '''
    }
    if (branchName == branchInEnv2) { // doesn't recognize var here
         '''
            0 2 * * * %ENV=env2
         '''
    }
    if (branchName == branchInEnv3) { // doesn't recognize var here
         '''
            0 1 * * * %ENV=env3
         '''
    }
}

pipeline {...}
```

Comment: How do you pass the branch name to the method?

Comment: Oh sorry, down in pipeline triggers I have:
`parameterizedCron(getCronJobsForBranch(env.BRANCH_NAME))`

I found my issue though. I didn't have elses so there was more that one potential return. Still I would like the option to return each, if there are multiples, so any idea how to return an array in jenkins (I guess that's just groovy)?